# Error when trying to make predictions with neuralnet

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using neuralnet function from the neuralnet package to train a neural network and then make predictions using a publicly available dataset, the german credit dataset that can be found at UCI Machine Learning repository.

Before applying the model I converted all the factor variables of the dataset to numeric dummy variables and then splitted the dataset to train and test.

My code and the messages I receive are the following:

```
library(neuralnet)     
class(german_train$Class)
    [1] "numeric"
    > model_nn1 <- neuralnet(formula = formula_nn, data = german_train, hidden = c(10 , 5), 
    +                        threshold = 0.01,  stepmax = 1e+05, rep = 3, 
    +                        startweights = rnorm(80),  learningrate.limit = NULL,  
    +                        learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2),  
    +                        learningrate=NULL, lifesign = "none",  lifesign.step = 1000, 
    +                        algorithm = "rprop+",  err.fct = "sse", act.fct = "logistic",  
    +                        linear.output = TRUE, exclude = NULL,  constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE)
    Warning message:
    some weights were randomly generated, because 'startweights' did not contain enough values 
    > predict_nn <- prediction(model_nn, german_test)
    Error in list.glm[[i]]$fitted.values : 
      $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
    > dim(german_test)
    [1] 300  62
    > dim(german_train)
    [1] 700  62
    > names(model_nn1)
     [1] "call"                "response"            "covariate"           "model.list"          "err.fct"            
     [6] "act.fct"             "linear.output"       "data"                "net.result"          "weights"            
    [11] "startweights"        "generalized.weights" "result.matrix" 

> formula_nn
Class ~ D_Status_of_existing_account__between_0_and_200 + D_Status_of_existing_account__greater_equal_to_200 + 
    D_Status_of_existing_account__less_than_0 + D_Status_of_existing_account__No_Account + 
    Duration_in_month + D_Credit_history__All_paid_in_this_bank + 
    D_Credit_history__Delay_in_the_Past + D_Credit_history__No_credits_or_All_paid + 
    D_Credit_history__Other_Accounts + D_Credit_history__Paid_duly_until_now + 
    D_Purpose__Appliances + D_Purpose__Business + D_Purpose__Car_new + 
    D_Purpose__Car_used + D_Purpose__Education + D_Purpose__Furniture_Equipment + 
    D_Purpose__Other + D_Purpose__Radio_TV + D_Purpose__Repairs + 
    D_Purpose__Retraining + Credit_amount + D_Savings_account_bonds__between_100_and_500 + 
    D_Savings_account_bonds__between_500_and_1000 + D_Savings_account_bonds__greater_than_1000 + 
    D_Savings_account_bonds__less_than_100 + D_Savings_account_bonds__Unknown_or_None + 
    D_Present_employment_since__between_1_and_4 + D_Present_employment_since__between_4_and_7 + 
    D_Present_employment_since__greater_than_7 + D_Present_employment_since__less_than_1 + 
    D_Present_employment_since__Unemployed + Installment_rate_in_percentage_of_disposable_income + 
    D_Personal_status_and_sex__Female_Non_Single + D_Personal_status_and_sex__Male_Divorced_Separated + 
    D_Personal_status_and_sex__Male_Married_Widowed + D_Personal_status_and_sex__Male_Single + 
    D_Other_debtors_guarantors__Co_applicant + D_Other_debtors_guarantors__Guarantor + 
    D_Other_debtors_guarantors__None + Present_residence_since + 
    D_Property__Building_Savings_LifeInsurance + D_Property__Car_Other + 
    D_Property__Real_Estate + D_Property__Unknown_None + Age + 
    D_Other_installment_plans__Bank + D_Other_installment_plans__None + 
    D_Other_installment_plans__Stores + D_Housing__For_Free + 
    D_Housing__Own + D_Housing__Rent + Number_of_existing_credits_at_this_bank + 
    D_Job__Manager_Professional_Self_Empl + D_Job__Skilled + 
    D_Job__Unemployed_Unskilled_Non_Resident + D_Job__Unskilled_Non_Resident + 
    Number_of_people_being_liable_to_provide_maintenance + D_Telephone__No_Telephone + 
    D_Telephone__Telephone + D_foreign_worker__Foreign_Worker + 
    D_foreign_worker__Not_Foreign_Worker
```

As you can see, I am getting an error message when I run the predict() function with the trained model.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please also show us formula_nn.

Comment: Why are you setting `startweights` if you are just choosing random numbers?  It does that by default and makes sure the dimensions match.

Comment: Can you provide data? See: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/823098)